# Transform str to int in nested loop while leaving actual strings untoutched

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Basically i want to transform a nested list kind of like this:

```
mylist = [['Paul','May','1'],['Maria','August','5'],['Elsa','February','3'],['Victor','September','7']]
```

Into a list where those values that could be integers but are put as strings are turned into integers. What I tried is:

```
int_list = [[int(x) for x in lst] for lst in mylist]
```

but this only works if all of them are integers - how can I achieve the Output below?

```
mylist = [['Paul','May',1],['Maria','August',5],['Elsa','February',3],['Victor','September',7]]
```

Comment: Do you mean `[[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in lst] for lst in mylist]`

Answer (score 0):

Since lists are mutable you can directly assign a new value to it.

```
mylist = [['Paul','May','1'],['Maria','August','5'],['Elsa','February','3'], 
['Victor','September','7']]

for lst in mylist:
  lst[2] = (int)(lst[2])

print(mylist)
# [['Paul', 'May', 1], ['Maria', 'August', 5], ['Elsa', 'February', 3], ['Victor', 'September', 7]]
```